# Questions about Android function parameters and new Folder Path recognition

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

As the title states.

1. Q: What kind of function **parametere** should be passed for the R.id ?

For example:

```
public void setExample(parameter){
  Button br = (Button) findViewById(R.id.**parameter**)
}
```

2. I wanted to put all the views in a certain folder, now for some reason:

   `setContentView(R.newFolder)`

R. - doesn't recognize new Folder, in which way new Folder can be created so that the path is recognized by R ?

Comment: "What kind of function parametere should be passed for the R.id ?" -- you would need to look up the identifier using [`getIdentifier()` on `Resources`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). Note that this is a bit slow, as it uses reflection, so consider caching the result. "in which way new Folder can be created so that the path is recognized by R ?" -- sorry, that is not supported. You cannot invent new resource types.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution!